# C++: strtok strange behaviour in last element of the line of input file?

Tags: c++, strtok

I am reading from a file (sample shown below), line by line, and for each line I use strtok to get the elements which are divided by tabs (as shown in the code). Now, when I create the file with the data, I do this: type "A", type tab, type "10" **press enter**, and so on. In this case, when the number is printed, it is followed by strange characters, and sometimes letters/numbers. "A patch" for this problem would be to enter the data in the following way: type "A", press tab, type "10" **press tab**. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening, and is there a better way to fix it?

```
sample.txt

 A    10
 B    20
 C    30 

 //str contains a line of the file           
 char * pch = strtok (str,"\t");
 //print character
 if(pch !=NULL){
    cout<<pch<<endl;
 }
 //print number
 pch = strtok (NULL, "\t");
 if(pch !=NULL){
    cout<<pch<<endl;
 }
```

Comment: It depends on how you read lines. This sounds like `str` is not null terminated i.e. it is a char buffer, and not a valid C string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what the reason of the problem is, but I "fixed" it by adding a tab ("\t") character at the end of each line that is read from the file.